# Setting Up Rails on EC2 and RDS

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I have an EC2 instance with my Rails code, and I'm trying to set it up to talk to Amazon RDS, but I'm getting an error when I try to start the rails server that I don't know how to correct:

```
/opt/bitnami/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/mysql2-0.3.11/lib/mysql2/client.rb:44:in `connect': Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2) (Mysql2::Error)
```

In my database.yml file, I have this:

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: development
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: secret
  host: localhost

production:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: mydbname
  username: myusername
  password: mypassword
  host: mypublicdnsformydb
  port: 3306
```

I assigned the RDS instance to the same security group as my EC2 which has:

```
22 (SSH)    0.0.0.0/0
80 (HTTP)   0.0.0.0/0   
443 (HTTPS) 0.0.0.0/0
```

When I add my PC's CIDR, I can connect to the instance perfectly fine, so I'm pretty sure that my username, password and host are correct.

Comment: Did you try to connect to RDS using `mysql -u<your-db-username> -p<your-db-password> -h<your-rds-public/private-dns>`? Can you try it and post an error output if any? Also, from your security group, I don't see any rule which talks about opening MySQL port 3306 on your RDS instance. That could be a flag as well.

Comment: Do you mean running that command from EC2?  The port seems to be open since I can log in to the RDS instance from my PC.

Comment: Yes, the command is to be executed from your EC2 instance. Your RDS security group indicates that the instance has SSH, HTTP and HTTPS access, but it doesn't provide MySQL access. By login from your local PC to the RDS instance, did you mean SSH login or MySQL login?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix this, I added this line in my database.yml for production

```
socket: /opt/bitnami/mysql/tmp/mysql.sock
```

and I ran my rails server specifying production as the environment:

```
rails s -e production
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that your development environment points to a mysql local, and not RDS.
By default Rails runs the development environment not the production, so I would try adding the same config of the production in the dev:

```
 development:
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  database: mydbname
  username: myusername
  password: mypassword
  host: mypublicdnsformydb
  port: 3306
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked just fine for me, add in the first line of your Gemfile

```
if RUBY_VERSION =~ /1.9/
Encoding.default_external = Encoding::UTF_8
Encoding.default_internal = Encoding::UTF_8
end
```

Source: Alan Ho Comment:
http://www.a.rnaud.net/2011/10/how-to-fix-invalid-byte-sequence-in-us-ascii-in-bundler-installation/